# "On" button for a Java calculator

Tags: java, netbeans, calculator

I am extremely new to programming with Java and I require assistance on how I may be be able to implement an ON button for my calculator.

I already have a user interface setup with all the numbers and plus/minus buttons using Netbeans. Everything's working as it should but how do I add an ON button?

Basically the calculator would not work till the ON button is pressed.

I've pasted the code here: 
http://pastebin.com/1Tfmb7wN

Comment: Can you please post your code

Comment: @Venkat I've pasted it above now

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When posting code, please use a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). It make it a lot easier for everyone to look through.

Comment: add a button for ON-OFF, and make sure that all the other buttons (except ON-OFF button) and screen are disabled(not clickable)
now in the action listener method of ON-OFF check whether the boolean is TRUE. if it is true then enable all the buttons and screen

Answer (score 0):

Add a field

```
on=false;
```

then add

```
Button onButton = new Button();
//some formatting;
onButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    on=true;
                            }
            });
```

finally an if statement surrounding the insides of your other handles

```
if(on){
//do something
}
```

Comment: Might be best to use Swing's _JButton_, instead of _Button_.

Comment: @Gullie how? Swing is starting to become deprecated as I understand it. JavaFX is the way to go.

Comment: Nevermind, I see now that the OP was using JButton in their existing code.

Comment: My mistake, I thought you were referring to AWT. ;) Looking back, I'm not sure how I missed that _.setOnAction()_... Still might be best for Chezz to use the _JButton_, as it looks like the rest of their program is using Swing.